# How much in Taken 2 was actually filmed in Istanbul?

Tags: film-location, taken-2

In Taken 2, the characters end up in Istanbul.  In the film we end up seeing quite a bit of a market and surrounding buildings.  Were any of the scenes actually filmed in Istanbul?  If so, which ones?

Comment: It was not istanbul. I am 32 years old and i didnt see these police cars in Istanbul :) They were tried to show the Turks as Arabs... I didnt like it!

Comment: I was looking forward to seeing Taken2 but was utterly disappointed by how it tried to portray Turks as Arabs. All the women showed in the film were wearing burcas. There was not a single Turkish woman dressed in western clothes. That is not modern Turkish women. Also there was a several shots of Blue Mosque and the old part of Istanbul. I can't understand why the producer couldn't show beautiful parts of Istanbul and the modern side of Turkey. Istanbul is a must-see city with lots of history and culture. Turkey is a Muslim country and we are proud to be Muslims, however, I strongly object to

Comment: There was not a single scene from the extraordinary christian church agia sofia, although this is the main attraction of the city. There were several shots from the blue mosque instead. Probably there was a banning from the Turkish authorities and if that so, it is a shame. It is almost impossible to shoot the scenery and do not include agia sofia. It is over there!!!! Only with a professiona cutting would do that. Shame on them. PS. By the way blue mosque's architect Sinan, had a Greek origin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neesson during a roundtable interview with a number of other journalists.  During the group interview Neeson talked about how the sequel came together, what it was like filming in Istanbul. They set it in Istanbul and he thought, ok that’s certainly one city I would love to see.

> What surprised you the most about working in Istanbul? Either the
>   under the circumstances of working there or also seeing some of the
>   sights in your free time.
>
> NEESON: Well, its- I’ve read so much about Constantinople as it used
>   to be from when I was doing Ridley Scott’s Kingdom of Heaven, you
>   know? Because it is the gateway from the west to the east and there’s
>   so many generations of conquests.  And you see it in the streets
>   there, you see foundation stones that were laid by, not just the
>   Romans, the Romans were only 2000 years ago, but generations thousands
>   of years ago, you know? So it such a rich incredible historical
>   culture, and you feel it.  And I think it adds something to our film,
>   it just gives it a texture.  All those car scenes we were doing, those
>   car chases and stuff, you know, yes we had a police presence, but the
>   shopkeepers, merchants on these tiny, narrow streets said, “No, no,
>   no; you shoot your film, but we’re keeping our shops open.” So you’d
>   have customers crossing streets all the time, they weren’t extras, and
>   we’re barreling up these streets in Mercedes Benz’s at reckless
>   speeds.

http://collider.com/taken-3-liam-neeson-interview/199412/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, definitely. You can see the Galata bridge (which connects Eminönü and Karaköy) very often, and the Eminönü district in the background with its Mosques..e.g. when they are on the ferryboat..and there will be also a guy selling Turkish tea on those ferryboats (www.sehirhatlari.com.tr). But I actually never saw a Mercedes cab there, and I think they used retired police cars  - but the car chase itself was in Istanbul, too.